# Using a Resource as an Attribute to a HTML Element in ASP.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I would like to have this piece of code in my .aspx file:

```
<input class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" type="button" name="BtnOK" id="Button2"
value="Close"
onclick="javascript:HandleOKButtonClick()"
accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,okbutton_accesskey%>" />
```

Unfortunately, ASP.net doesn't seem to like that:

```
An error occurred during the processing of /_layouts/MyPage/Info.aspx.
Literal expressions like '<%$Resources:wss,okbutton_accesskey%>' are not allowed.
Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:wss,okbutton_accesskey%>" />
instead
```

That doesn't work in this situation as that would mean nesting the Literal between the quotes of the accesskey attribute, which causes a "The tag contains duplicate 'ID' attributes" error.

Is there a way to use a string from a resource without having to change the input to an asp:Button? I guess there has to be a way using `<%=`, but I don't know how I would address the resource itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the correct syntax is `<%= Resources.wss.okbutton_accesskey %>`.

In any case, all the resources, once compiled are accessible through Resources.[ResourceFileName].[Key]